# Aggregator channels do not update anymore

Tags: feeds

For a half year, I have run a website with all sorts of news channels displayed trough the core aggregator module on www.tri-portaal.be. Once in a while, I keep adding sources.

But recently my news channels do not update anymore. Even not after running CRON.
In the column, next update is stated 0sec.

Although I can update them manually, but that is a huge job to do every day.

I have searched the forums, but I can't seem to solve my problem.

Can somebody please help me or help how me diagnosing?
I am running drupal 7.43.